# Spring Boot MockMvc multithreaded test does not give same result as Runtime

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I'm trying to test multithreaded code in Spring boot with MockMvc.

The code works as expected at Runtime but running in a Spring boot MockMvc test results in an empty list.

The original repository contains records, even in the constructor of the Callable implementation, but when call() is called there are no records in it's repository.

```
package com.xti.service.impl;

import com.xti.domain.Car;
import com.xti.repository.CarRepository;
import com.xti.service.CarService;
import com.xti.service.dto.CarDTO;
import com.xti.service.mapper.CarMapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 * Service Implementation for managing {@link Car}.
 */
@Service
@Transactional
public class CarServiceImpl implements CarService {

    private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CarServiceImpl.class);

    private final CarRepository carRepository;

    private final CarMapper carMapper;

    public CarServiceImpl(CarRepository carRepository, CarMapper carMapper) {
        this.carRepository = carRepository;
        this.carMapper = carMapper;
    }

    /**
     * Save a car.
     *
     * @param carDTO the entity to save.
     * @return the persisted entity.
     */
    @Override
    public CarDTO save(CarDTO carDTO) {
        log.debug("Request to save Car : {}", carDTO);
        Car car = carMapper.toEntity(carDTO);
        car = carRepository.save(car);
        return carMapper.toDto(car);
    }

    /**
     * Get all the cars.
     *
     * @return the list of entities.
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public List<CarDTO> findAll() {
        log.debug("Request to get all Cars");
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        CarTask carTask = new CarTask(carRepository);

        log.info("Original findAll().size() result {}", carRepository.findAll().size());
        try {
            return executorService.submit(carTask).get()
                .stream()
                .map(carMapper::toDto)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    // TODO why does this work at Runtime but not in MockMvc test
    public class CarTask implements Callable<List<Car>> {

        private final CarRepository otherCarRepository;

        public CarTask(CarRepository otherCarRepository) {
            this.otherCarRepository = otherCarRepository;
            log.info("From CarTask constructor call() findAll().size()  {}", otherCarRepository.findAll().size());
        }


        @Override
        public List<Car> call() {
            log.info("From CarTask call() findAll().size()  {}", otherCarRepository.findAll().size());
            return otherCarRepository.findAll();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get one car by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     * @return the entity.
     */
    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Optional<CarDTO> findOne(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to get Car : {}", id);
        return carRepository.findById(id)
            .map(carMapper::toDto);
    }

    /**
     * Delete the car by id.
     *
     * @param id the id of the entity.
     */
    @Override
    public void delete(Long id) {
        log.debug("Request to delete Car : {}", id);
        carRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
}
```

CarResourceIT

```
package com.xti.web.rest;

import com.xti.MultithreadedTestingApp;
import com.xti.domain.Car;
import com.xti.repository.CarRepository;
import com.xti.service.CarService;
import com.xti.service.dto.CarDTO;
import com.xti.service.mapper.CarMapper;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.test.context.support.WithMockUser;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.hasItem;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders.*;
import static org.springframework.test.web.servlet.result.MockMvcResultMatchers.*;
package com.xti.web.rest;
@SpringBootTest(classes = MultithreadedTestingApp.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@WithMockUser
public class CarResourceIT {
private static final String DEFAULT_MODEL = "AAAAAAAAAA";
private static final String UPDATED_MODEL = "BBBBBBBBBB";

@Autowired
private CarRepository carRepository;

@Autowired
private CarMapper carMapper;

@Autowired
private CarService carService;

@Autowired
private EntityManager em;

@Autowired
private MockMvc restCarMockMvc;

private Car car;


/**
 * Create an entity for this test.
 *
 * This is a static method, as tests for other entities might also need it,
 * if they test an entity which requires the current entity.
 */
public static Car createEntity(EntityManager em) {
    Car car = new Car()
        .model(DEFAULT_MODEL);
    return car;
}
/**
 * Create an updated entity for this test.
 *
 * This is a static method, as tests for other entities might also need it,
 * if they test an entity which requires the current entity.
 */
public static Car createUpdatedEntity(EntityManager em) {
    Car car = new Car()
        .model(UPDATED_MODEL);
    return car;
}

@BeforeEach
public void initTest() {
    car = createEntity(em);
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void createCar() throws Exception {
    int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = carRepository.findAll().size();

    // Create the Car
    CarDTO carDTO = carMapper.toDto(car);
    restCarMockMvc.perform(post("/api/cars")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(carDTO)))
        .andExpect(status().isCreated());

    // Validate the Car in the database
    List<Car> carList = carRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(carList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate + 1);
    Car testCar = carList.get(carList.size() - 1);
    assertThat(testCar.getModel()).isEqualTo(DEFAULT_MODEL);
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void createCarWithExistingId() throws Exception {
    int databaseSizeBeforeCreate = carRepository.findAll().size();

    // Create the Car with an existing ID
    car.setId(1L);
    CarDTO carDTO = carMapper.toDto(car);

    // An entity with an existing ID cannot be created, so this API call must fail
    restCarMockMvc.perform(post("/api/cars")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(carDTO)))
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

    // Validate the Car in the database
    List<Car> carList = carRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(carList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeCreate);
}


@Test
@Transactional
public void getAllCars() throws Exception {
    // TODO why does CarRepository not contain any Cars?
    // Initialize the database
    carRepository.saveAndFlush(car);

    // Get all the carList
    restCarMockMvc.perform(get("/api/cars?sort=id,desc"))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].id").value(hasItem(car.getId().intValue())))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.[*].model").value(hasItem(DEFAULT_MODEL)));
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void getCar() throws Exception {
    // Initialize the database
    carRepository.saveAndFlush(car);

    // Get the car
    restCarMockMvc.perform(get("/api/cars/{id}", car.getId()))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id").value(car.getId().intValue()))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.model").value(DEFAULT_MODEL));
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void getNonExistingCar() throws Exception {
    // Get the car
    restCarMockMvc.perform(get("/api/cars/{id}", Long.MAX_VALUE))
        .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void updateCar() throws Exception {
    // Initialize the database
    carRepository.saveAndFlush(car);

    int databaseSizeBeforeUpdate = carRepository.findAll().size();

    // Update the car
    Car updatedCar = carRepository.findById(car.getId()).get();
    // Disconnect from session so that the updates on updatedCar are not directly saved in db
    em.detach(updatedCar);
    updatedCar
        .model(UPDATED_MODEL);
    CarDTO carDTO = carMapper.toDto(updatedCar);

    restCarMockMvc.perform(put("/api/cars")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(carDTO)))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());

    // Validate the Car in the database
    List<Car> carList = carRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(carList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeUpdate);
    Car testCar = carList.get(carList.size() - 1);
    assertThat(testCar.getModel()).isEqualTo(UPDATED_MODEL);
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void updateNonExistingCar() throws Exception {
    int databaseSizeBeforeUpdate = carRepository.findAll().size();

    // Create the Car
    CarDTO carDTO = carMapper.toDto(car);

    // If the entity doesn't have an ID, it will throw BadRequestAlertException
    restCarMockMvc.perform(put("/api/cars")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(TestUtil.convertObjectToJsonBytes(carDTO)))
        .andExpect(status().isBadRequest());

    // Validate the Car in the database
    List<Car> carList = carRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(carList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeUpdate);
}

@Test
@Transactional
public void deleteCar() throws Exception {
    // Initialize the database
    carRepository.saveAndFlush(car);

    int databaseSizeBeforeDelete = carRepository.findAll().size();

    // Delete the car
    restCarMockMvc.perform(delete("/api/cars/{id}", car.getId())
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
        .andExpect(status().isNoContent());

    // Validate the database contains one less item
    List<Car> carList = carRepository.findAll();
    assertThat(carList).hasSize(databaseSizeBeforeDelete - 1);
}
```

}

The test use H2 with this configuration:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: multithreaded_testing
  datasource:
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:multithreaded_testing;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    name:
    username:
    password:
    hikari:
      auto-commit: false
```

Failed test: com.xti.web.rest.CarResourceIT#getAllCars

Impl: com.xti.service.impl.CarServiceImpl#findAll

https://bitbucket.org/Kelvijn/mockmvc_multithreaded_problem/src/master/

Comment: Please add your full test case and not just a snippet.

Comment: I added the whole impl class and test :)

Comment: Setting auto commit to true does the trick...

Comment: Enabling auto-commit isn't the solution, this means something else is wrong withyour setup... The problem is that your test has a single tx, whereas your actual code doesn't. So you would need multiple txs in your test as well.